# community.aws.elb_application_lb: How to assign next priority to the new added rule in a listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elb

I created an ansible playbook that adds a new rule to a load balancer listener via the community.aws.elb_application_lb plugin.

```yaml
- name: Create the listener rule in the load balancer
  community.aws.elb_application_lb:
    ...
    listeners:
      - Protocol: "{{ listener.protocol }}"
        ...
        Rules:
          - Conditions:
              - Field: host-header
                Values: "{{ domains }}"
            Actions:
              - TargetGroupName: "{{ target_group_name }}"
                Type: forward
            Priority: "{{ some_value }}"
```

Looks like the Priority parameter is mandatory and must be an integer. For any new added rule, I need to find a way to just tell the plugin to set the next priority to the newly added rule. For example if I have 10 rules defined in the listener, the newly added rule will have the Priority 11.

I know I can compute that last priority by calling the `community.aws.elb_application_lb_info` plugin and parsing the resulted json for getting the last priority and adding 1. I've already tried that but the problem is that my playbook might be run in parallel. So in parallel executions, it might happen that the running playbooks both determine that the next priority is 11 (because at the moment when they gathered information about the load balancer listener there were 10 rules defined). So both are adding a new rule having the priority 11, the last playbook overwriting basically the rule defined by the previous playbooks.

If the playbooks would run in sequence and not in parallel, this problem would be gone. But unfortunately the requirement is that they should be able to run in parallel.

So, is there any possibility to just tell the plugin to allocate the next priority to the newly added rule? Or any other approach to just avoid overwriting of the new rule?

Comment: Does awscli do what you're describing? because if not, the python module is not going to get smarter than the APIs that AWS provides via boto; if you don't care about the ordering, then some retry loops could help any such concurrency concerns

Comment: @mdaniel In the end I set `serial: 1` and the issue has gone. Surprisingly looks like the playbook runs faster when running serially compared to when it runs in parallel. Thanks for your suggestion anyway. ;-)